# Проблема с циклом while C

Tags: c, while

Столкнулся с проблемой использования цикла while в своем коде.Мне нужно чтобы пользователь выбрал несколько товаров.В данной задаче я не понимаю как это осуществить.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int t,k,i;
    printf("Введите кол-во товара\n");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("Введите кол-во раз повторов\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    while (i <=5){
        printf("Введите номер товара\n");
        scanf("%d",&t);
        i-1;
    }
    switch (t) {
        case 1:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 1 товара %f",29.80 * k);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 2 товара %f",45.50 * k);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 3 товара %f",9.98 * k);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 4 товара %f",44.90 * k);
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 5 товара %f",67.80 * k);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Ошибка");
    }
 
 
 
}
```

```
Пример

Введите кол-во товара:
2
Введите кол-во раз повторов:
2
Введите номер товара:
4
Введите номер товара:
1
Кол-во проданного 4 товара :
Ответ
Кол-во проданного 1 товара :
Ответ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уловил немного, что вы хотите, но в вашем коде явно ошибки

```
int main(){
    int t,k,i;
    printf("Введите кол-во товара\n");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("Введите кол-во раз повторов\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    while (i <=5){ //По заданному условию, цикл будет работать пока количесво повторов не станет больше или равным пяти
        printf("Введите номер товара\n");
        scanf("%d",&t);
        i-1; // данное действие вообще ничего не делает для цикла
    }
    switch (t) { // если хотите получать ответ, лучше поместить switch внутрь цикла
        case 1:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 1 товара %f",29.80 * k);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 2 товара %f",45.50 * k);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 3 товара %f",9.98 * k);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 4 товара %f",44.90 * k);
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 5 товара %f",67.80 * k);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Ошибка");
    }
}
```

Так, в итоге, ваше код должен выглядеть так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int t,k,i;
    printf("Введите кол-во товара\n");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("Введите кол-во раз повторов\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    while (i != 0){ // исправил здесь
        printf("Введите номер товара\n");
        scanf("%d",&t);
        i = i-1; // исправил здесь
        switch (t) { // перенес switch
        case 1:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 1 товара %f",29.80 * k);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 2 товара %f",45.50 * k);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 3 товара %f",9.98 * k);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 4 товара %f",44.90 * k);
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Кол-во проданного 5 товара %f",67.80 * k);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Ошибка");
    }
    }
    
}
```

Чтобы ответ вышел таким:

```
Введите кол-во товара
2
Введите кол-во раз повторов
2
Введите номер товара
2
Кол-во проданного 2 товара 91.000000
Введите номер товара
4
Кол-во проданного 4 товара 89.800000
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну, две главные ошибки вам исправили — это неверно закрытое тело цикла и отсутствие изменения счетчика. Здесь бы было проще с циклом `for`, кстати, но если это работа именно с `while`, то оставим его.

Но почему бы вам не упростить код и не отказаться от надоедливого повторения вывода в `switch` — например, так:

```
int main()
{
    int n,k;
    printf("Введите кол-во товара: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("Введите кол-во раз повторов: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n-->0)
    {
        int t;
        printf("Введите номер товара: ");
        scanf("%d",&t);
        double cnt[5] = {29.80,45.50,9.98,44.90,67.80};
        if (t < 1 || t > 5) printf("Ошибка\n");
        else printf("Кол-во проданного %d товара %lf\n", t, cnt[t-1]*k);
    }
}
```

Согласитесь, и компактнее, и легче воспринимается...